# Moving an Image to Origin

Tags: swift, imageview, jquery-animate, move

I am currently working on an animation project for an Apple Development class where we are moving and animating an ImageView. I can move the image, but I'm stumped on how to return it to the origin location, preferably using the same button.
Code for the move animation is as follows:

```
@IBAction func move(_ sender: Any) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {self.imageView.frame.origin.y -= 200
    }, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: don't use frames if you have constraints active. They don't get along with each other very well. create constraints outlet and update them in `UIView.animate`

Answer (score 1):

declare a variable that will hold the value of your y origin when the view loaded. and also declare a variable that will check if the imageview is currently animating or not.

```
var onLoadFrameYOrigin : CGFloat = 0.0
var isAnimating : Bool = false


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    onLoadFrameYOrigin = self.searchView.frame.origin.y
}

@IBAction func move(_ sender: Any) {
    if !isAnimating {
        self.isAnimating = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            if self.onLoadFrameYOrigin == self.imageView.frame.origin.y {
                self.imageView.frame.origin.y -= 200
            } else {
                self.imageView.frame.origin.y = onLoadFrameYOrigin
            }
        }) { _ in
            self.isAnimating = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note : if you have make outlet of constraint of imageView then please
>   update constraint value during animation not frame.

1) make variable first

```
var isBack : Bool = false
```

Now in your button action :

```
@IBAction func move(_ sender: Any) {

   if  isBack == false
   {
        isBack = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {self.imageView.frame.origin.y -= 200
       }, completion: nil)
   }
   else
   {
        isBack = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {self.imageView.frame.origin.y += 200
       }, completion: nil)
   }

}
```